# Not getting correct results displayed from register

Tags: verilog, multiplexer, register, alu, testbench

I am trying to input the numbers 1,0,3,2,32'hFFFFFFFF,32'h00000001 into the registers 0,1,2,3,6, and 7 respectively. I am doing this through `always @(posedge clk)` but in my `datapath_tb` module (My Testbench). I am then performing Bitwise AND, OR, ADD, and Subtract from my `alu` module. Then storing these results in registers 4,5,6,7 respectively. I think the register is my `write_data` array, so I use `write_data[1]` to call register 1 for example. I My result is this:

```
r4 = x
r5 = x
r6 = x
r7 = x
r22 = x
```

I want to know what I am doing wrong. Here are my modules.

```
module datapath_tb(input [31:0] write_data);
parameter SIZE = 32;     
reg clk;
reg write;
reg [4:0] write_addr;
//input reg [31:0] write_data;
reg [4:0] read_addr1;
reg [4:0] read_addr2;
wire [31:0] read_data1;
wire [31:0] read_data2;
// Instantiate the register file
Register rf_1 (.clk(clk), .write_en(write), .write_addr(write_addr), .write_data(write_data), .read_addr1(read_addr1), .read_addr2(read_addr2), .read_data1(read_data1), .read_data2(read_data2));
// Instantiate the ALU
  alu #(SIZE) alu_1 (.input1(read_data1), .input2(read_data2), .control(write), .alu_result(write_data));
// Create a clocking signal
 always begin
   # 10;
   clk = 1; 
   # 10;
   clk = 0;
 end 
//write_addr[0] = 1;
always @(posedge clk)
  begin
  // Write DIGIT0 into register 0
        if(write)
            write_addr = 1;
            write_addr = write_data[0];
  // Write DIGIT1 into register 1
        if(write)
            write_addr = 0;
            write_addr = write_data[1];
        if(write)
            write_addr = 3;
            write_addr = write_data[2];
        if(write)
            write_addr = 2;
            write_addr = write_data[3];
        if(write)
            write_addr = 32'hFFFFFFFF;
            write_addr = write_data[20];
        if(write)
            write_addr = 32'h00000001;
            write_addr = write_data[21];
  end

//Using alu to perform operations
  alu alu_add (.input1(write_data[0]), .input2(write_data[1]), .control(2), .alu_result(write_data[4]));//ADD
  alu alu_sub (.input1(write_data[2]), .input2(write_data[3]), .control(6), .alu_result(write_data[5]));//SUB
  alu alu_and (.input1(write_data[0]), .input2(write_data[1]), .control(0), .alu_result(write_data[6]));//BW AND
  alu alu_or (.input1(write_data[0]), .input2(write_data[1]), .control(1), .alu_result(write_data[7]));//BW OR
  alu alu_check (.input1(write_data[20]), .input2(write_data[21]), .control(2), .alu_result(write_data[22]));//ADD for test if circuit works from ALU's part

initial begin
  $display("r4 = %h", write_data[4]);
  $display("r5 = %h", write_data[5]);
  $display("r6 = %h", write_data[6]);
  $display("r7 = %h", write_data[7]);
  $display("r22 = %h", write_data[22]);
  
end
endmodule
```

```
module alu #(parameter SIZE=32) (input wire [SIZE-1:0] input1, input2, input wire [2:0] control,
                                 output reg [SIZE-1:0] alu_result);
//wire [2:0] control;
reg overflow;

always @(*)
begin
    case(control)
        0: alu_result = input1 & input2;
        1: alu_result = input1 | input2;
        2: alu_result = input1 + input2;
        3: alu_result = (input1 < input2)?1'b1:1'b0; //unsigned, no additional bits to worry about
        4: alu_result = input1 ^ input2;
        5: alu_result = ~(input1 | input2);
        6: alu_result = input1 - input2;
        7: alu_result = (~(input1 + 1) < input2)?1'b1:1'b0; //2's comp is ~ & +1
        default: alu_result = input1 & input2;
    endcase
    
    if(alu_result > 32'hFFFFFFFF)
    begin
        overflow <= alu_result;
    end
end
endmodule // alu
```

```
module Register #(parameter WIDTH = 32)(
input clk,
input [4:0] read_addr1,
input [4:0] read_addr2,
input write_en,
input [4:0] write_addr,
input [WIDTH-1:0] write_data,
output [WIDTH-1:0] read_data1,
output [WIDTH-1:0] read_data2);
reg [WIDTH-1:0] reg_arr[31:0];

always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        if(write_en)
            reg_arr[write_addr] <= write_data;
    end

assign read_data1 = reg_arr[read_addr1];
assign read_data2 = reg_arr[read_addr2];

endmodule
```

Also, would adding a mux2 module help in any way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a typo in your first section of code?
You have two lines in a row trying to update write_addr.
Also, write_addr is a vector so you can't fill it with a single bit write_data[0].
Also, if you do have two lines after an if then you want brackets around both.

Comment: @td127 Brackets in Verilog are for concatenation. He should be using "begin" and "end".

Answer (score -1):

In your test bench always block, you have 6 "if" statements all of which have "write_addr" being assigned different values on the condition "write". "write_addr" can't be multiple values at the same time.

You also should be using "begin" and "end" around "if" statements:

```
if(condition)begin
   action 1
   action 2
end
```

You have other issues as well, such as trying to put 32 bits into "write address" when it's a 5 bit register. You seem to have a fundamental lack of knowledge on digital design in general. I'd suggest starting with a simpler design. YouTube has many good tutorials on Verilog.

Check out the following site:

[NANDLAND](https://www.nandland.com/)

I've found this is a very good resource for beginners.

Comment: Do you know if i can do something similar to this:

```
always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if(write) begin
      write_data[0] <= 1;
      write_data[1] <= 0;
      write_data[2] <= 3;
      write_data[3] <= 2;
      write_data[20] <= 32'hFFFFFFFF;
      write_data[21] <= 32'h00000001;
    end
  end
```
My main objective is to just get these numbers in to these registers. But every way I try doing it seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, that should work. As long as you bracket all those lines, and by bracket I mean putting them inside a begin/end construct.